# Elixir/Phoenix - for loop iterator in template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

A certain number is passed from the controller to the template. For example, this number is 5. In the template, I need to display numbers from 1 to a given number (5).
For example, in PHP this could be done like this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=given_number; $i++){
    echo $i;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out which is the best way to do this in Elixir/Phoenix. I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: `Enum.each(1..number, &IO.puts/1)`.

Comment: or even `1..number |> Enum.each( &IO.puts/1 )`

Comment: Its work in IEX, but not work in the template( I tried to output in a template using  <%= Enum.each(1..3, fn(x) -> IO.puts(x) end) %> but have output atom :ok

Comment: Restate the question then, explicitly pointing out you need it in template. `Enum.each/1` returns `:ok` that gets output, obviously.

Comment: I indicated this in the question. I apologize if I didn’t formulate this correctly

Answer (score 8):

Using this code, I managed to solve the problem:

```elixir
<%= for x <- 1..@number do %>
  <%= x %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a HTML tag or a function component should be rendered for each `@number`, one can use the `:for` expression (here with a `span` as an example):

```
<span :for={x <- @number}>
  x
</span>
```

This is the same as

```
<%= for x <- 1..@number do %>
  <span><%= x %></span>
<% end %>
```